# How to fix - Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, nofollow, noindex

I have just received an email regarding Index coverage issues for my site.
The following file is indexed by the Google:

`root-of-my-site/files/custom.js`

Please note that I have disallowed `/files` folder in my .htaccess though Google has indexed a URL from that folder.

Please let me know how should I de-index my URL forever!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also note that the accepted answer was one that the OP could have easily Googled.  This shows a clear lack of research or effort by OP to answer their own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this article from Goole itself: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7440203?hl=en

Some from there:

> **Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt:** The page was indexed, despite being blocked by robots.txt (Google always respects robots.txt, but this doesn't help [if someone else links to it](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608#robotted-but-indexed)). This is marked as a warning because we're not sure if you intended to block the page from search results. If you do want to block this page, [robots.txt is not the correct mechanism to avoid being indexed.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608) To avoid being indexed you should either [use 'noindex'](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710) or prohibit anonymous access to the page using auth. You can use the [robots.txt tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool) to determine which rule is blocking this page. Because of the robots.txt, any snippet shown for the page will probably be sub-optimal. If you do not want to block this page, update your robots.txt file to unblock your page.

You can watch this video for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlniBqL_0Zc